# Solving for T in a parametric equation when x is known

Tags: parametric, cubics

I want to find the y value and the t value when x is known in a parametric equation.

example

```
x(t)=1.85t³-2.75t²+1.89t+0
y(t)2.58t³-3.65t²+1.27+0
```

when x=0 and y=0 for the vertex (0,0), how do I solve for t? I cant find anything on it. Can you point me in the right direction of the process?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $y(t)=0$ cannot be solved for $t$ "nicely", unless the question contains a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You can factor $t$ out of $x(t)$ and solve the resulting quadratic equation. Now check, which solutions satisfy $y(t)=0$ as well.

Comment: thank you, but i think i was going in the wrong direction. I want to find y and t when only x is known, if i have the parametric equation.